# pyspark: A more efficent to unpack a column of arrays into multiple columns?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a column of arrays which can be created like this

```
df = spark.CreateDataFrame(["[{\"key\":1}, {\"key\":2}"], "tmp")

from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.\
        withColumn("tmp", F.from_json(in_col_name, "array<string>")).\
        cache()

# obtain the maximum number of components in the array
max_arr_len = df.select(F.size(tmp)).rdd.max()[0]

for i in range(max_arr_len )
   df = df.withColumn("tmp"+str(i), F.col("tmp").getItem(i))
```

Imagine if I am running this on 100 million rows. I think looping to use the `getItem` is inefficient. Is there a way to obtain all `max_arr_len` columns at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually loop is not so inefficient in this case. `getItem` is a lazy transformation, so Spark is able to optimize your code and perform all loop steps as a single step.
Look at the plan using `df.explain()`:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [in_col_name#820, tmp#822, tmp#822[0] AS tmp0#945, tmp#822[1] AS tmp1#949]
+- InMemoryTableScan [in_col_name#820, tmp#822]
      +- InMemoryRelation [in_col_name#820, tmp#822], StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
            +- Project [in_col_name#820, from_json(ArrayType(StructType(StructField(key,IntegerType,true)),true), in_col_name#820, Some(Etc/UTC)) AS tmp#822]
               +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[in_col_name#820]
```

You'll notice that all element extractions are performed on the same line:

```
tmp#822[0] AS tmp0#945, tmp#822[1] AS tmp1#949
```